# How do I show ProgressDialog from AsyncTask which is returning boolean value from doInBackground()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Activity from which I am calling AsyncTask for sign in.
If it returns true then, switch to another activity.

```
signIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("On Click Sign In", "Before PD shown");
        //          pd.show();

        Log.d("On Click Sign In", "After PD shown");
        try {
            if (new SignIn(SessionLogin.this).execute(email, pass).get())
            {
                Log.d("onClick", "True");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(SessionLogin.this, DashBoardMain.class);
                //              pd.dismiss();
                Log.d("SessionLogin", "true SignIn");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(SessionLogin.this, "Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(SessionLogin.this, Woftos_sign_in_up.class);
                //          pd.dismiss();
                Log.d("SessionLogin", "false || Null SignIn");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

});
```

AsyncTask in which I am connecting to database and returning values.
Till the asynctask runs, I wanna show ProgressDialog.

```
public class SignIn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    String queryString;

    ProgressDialog PD;
    public static String NodeID=null;
    public static String Gender=null;
    public static String imageName=null;
    String result;
    Context context;

    public SignIn(Context mcontext){
        context=mcontext;
        Log.d("constructor", "context "+context.toString());
        PD=new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
        PD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        PD.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        PD.setMessage("Signing in...");
        PD.setCancelable(false);
        PD.setIndeterminate(true);
        PD.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean x) {   
    super.onPostExecute(x);
    if(PD.isShowing()){
        Log.d("onPostExecute", "ProgressDialog b4 dismiss");
        PD.dismiss();
        Log.d("onPostExecute", "ProgressDialog after dismiss");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        Log.d("in async", "" + arg0[0] + " " + arg0[1]);


            try {
                //Connecting to database
                DBConnect.connect();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            queryString = "{\"query\":\"START n=node(*) WHERE n.Email_Id='"
                    + arg0[0] + "' AND n.Password='" + arg0[1]
                    + "' RETURN n.Password,id(n),n.Gender,n.Profile_Photo\", \"params\":{}}";

            try {
                //Sending Query
                DBConnect.sendQuery(queryString);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                //Getting result of Query
             result = DBConnect.readInputStream();

            JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray nameArray = obj1.getJSONArray("data");
            int res=nameArray.length();
            if(res==0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            result = nameArray.getJSONArray(0).getString(0);
            NodeID = nameArray.getJSONArray(0).getString(1);
            Gender = nameArray.getJSONArray(0).getString(2);
            //imageName = nameArray.getJSONArray(0).getString(3);

            Log.d("NodeID-Gender in SignIn", ""+result+" " + NodeID+" "+Gender);
            DashBoardMain.nodeID=NodeID;
            DashBoardMain.DBGender=Gender;
            //DashBoardMain.imageName=imageName;
            return true;
            //DashBoardMain.imageName=imageName;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

No matter what I do, ProgressDialog never shows up. Rest of the code works fine to connect with Database and returns the values.
Please help..

Comment: Do you see  Log.d("onPostExecute", "ProgressDialog b4 dismiss");

    Log.d("onPostExecute", "ProgressDialog after dismiss"); these logs in logcat?

Comment: That means your progress dialog was showing might be the doInBackground is just so fast you cant see the progressDialog, will you please try adding delay by 1-2 seconds in do in background and check if it is showing progress dialog

Comment: Not related to your issue I would suggest you to use onPreExecute while using AsyncTask it will help you and its good according to standards as everyone else did specify this in their answers

Comment: To get the result of 
Log.d("NodeID-Gender in SignIn", ""+result+" " + NodeID+" "+Gender); on logcat, it takes almost 1-2 mins but progress bar doesn't come up.

Comment: I tried putting it in onPreExecute() but still ProgressDialog doesn't shows up.

Comment: D.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); remove this and check

Comment: The dialog must be created on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

try like this in asynctask,

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       PD=new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
    PD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    PD.setTitle("Please Wait...");
    PD.setMessage("Signing in...");
    PD.setCancelable(false);
    PD.setIndeterminate(true);
    PD.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        PD.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `pre excecute` like this.

```
public SignIn(Context mcontext){
    context=mcontext;
    Log.d("constructor", "context "+context.toString());
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    PD=new ProgressDialog(context);
    PD.setTitle("Please Wait...");
    PD.setMessage("Signing in...");
    PD.setCancelable(false);
    PD.setIndeterminate(true);
    PD.show();
        }
```

**OR---------------** it may because of your process is completed suddenly so `progressdialog` may closed suddenly.To avoid this in your `post execute` try :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean x) {   
super.onPostExecute(x);
if(PD.isShowing()){
    Log.d("onPostExecute", "ProgressDialog b4 dismiss");
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         PD.dismiss();
    }}, 3000);

    Log.d("onPostExecute", "ProgressDialog after dismiss");
    }
}
```

**OR------------------------**

Remove the `.get()` from your aynctask call,`get()` waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result. This means, that you are blocking your UI thread, waiting for the result.

Solution: Don't call get

Usually, you will call a function (callback) in the postExecute.

Comment: Tried it, still the same.

Comment: Tried it, still no progress dialog.

Comment: I gave you another sol in or part of my answer, try it.

Comment: Hey, ProgressDialog came up but after execution of doInBackground(), in onPostExecute().

I want progressdialog when doInBackground() is running.

Comment: I think your doing background process is very small and it completed in very small time, the progress dialog will start at PD.show(); itself.

Comment: But getting result from database after sending query takes 1-2 mins as 
Log.d("NodeID-Gender in SignIn", ""+result+" " + NodeID+" "+Gender);
takes 1-2 mins to display.

Comment: I think you have to remove .get() from the asynctask call, get fuction block the UI thats the reason, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Override the OnPreExecute() of AsyncTask and paste

context=mcontext;
Log.d("constructor", "context "+context.toString());
PD=new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
PD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
PD.setTitle("Please Wait...");
PD.setMessage("Signing in...");
PD.setCancelable(false);
PD.setIndeterminate(true);
PD.show();
```

Comment: I feel navigation code is closing the dialog immediately after it got opened.  Try Using startActivity() in on PostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

show your ProgressDialog in onPreExecute() method and dismiss it in onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask.. like this.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {


 PD=new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
    PD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    PD.setTitle("Please Wait...");
    PD.setMessage("Signing in...");
    PD.setCancelable(false);
    PD.setIndeterminate(true);
    PD.show();

};
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean x) {   
super.onPostExecute(x);
if(PD.isShowing()){
    Log.d("onPostExecute", "ProgressDialog b4 dismiss");
    PD.dismiss();
    Log.d("onPostExecute", "ProgressDialog after dismiss");
    }
}
```